# Get key and value from an array of SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simple-xml-converter

I have an array structure like this (output by `print_r(array)`):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [items] => Array ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [walson] => 986 
            [john] => 01 
            [merry] => 234 ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [nelson] => 987 
            [richard] => 01 
            [joan] => 345 )))
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [danny] => 989 
            [soffie] => 02 
            [roland] => 345 )))
```

How can I get output like this in PHP:

```
0, walson 986, john 01, merry 234
1, nelson 987, richard 01, joan 345
2, danny 989, soffie 02, roland 345
```

Comment: When posting questions about XML, it's more helpful to post the original XML rather than an object dump.

Comment: the original xml is 6546 records

Comment: OK - so post a sample of the data - in the same way you've posted a sample of the output.

Comment: i dont create data. i just got an xml file just the way it is. its too complex. but i've just found the answer, as i wrote it below.

Answer (score 4):

You can use php function like

```
$simple = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$arr = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);
print_r($arr);
```

this will give you array result like

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [walson] => 986 
                    [john] => 01
                    [merry] => 234
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XML is quite easy once you understand how to use the proper API's, with SimpleXML it is easy to access the structure of the data using object notation (`->items` in the code accesses the `<items>` elements).

```
$data = <<< XML
<Data>
   <items>
     <walson>986</walson>
     <john>01</john>
     <merry>234</merry>
   </items>
   <items>
     <walson>1986</walson>
     <john>101</john>
     <merry>1234</merry>
   </items>
   <items>
     <walson>2986</walson>
     <john>201</john>
     <merry>2234</merry>
   </items>
</Data>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$output = [];
$index = 0;
foreach ( $xml->items as $item )    {
    $itemData = [];
    foreach ( $item as $key => $element )   {
        $itemData[$key] = (string)$element;
    }
    echo $index++.", ".implode(", ", $itemData).PHP_EOL;
    $output[] = $itemData;
}

print_r($output);
```

This uses a couple of loops to access each element at a time, the inner loop just reads each element and creates a key/value pair from the element name and contents.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The point is how i can get the key and value from such output array of simpleXMLElement Object:

```
$simple=simplexml_load_file($xml_file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$array = get_object_vars($simple->items);

foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
  //by using output like this
  echo "key:".$key."-".$val."<br>";
}
```

some of original xml - more than 6000 records (edited):

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VFPData xml:space="preserve">
    <xsd:schema id="VFPData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="VFPData" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="items" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="budgyear">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="doctype">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="2"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="unitcode">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
....
....
                                <xsd:element name="ibcode">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:maxLength value="2"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <items>
        <budgyear>2018</budgyear>
        <doctype>01</doctype>
        <unitcode>986860</unitcode>
...
...
        <ibcode>020</ibcode>
</items></VFPData>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//should be something like this:

foreach ($array->items as $key => $item )    {
 echo "\n<br>".$key;
  foreach ($item as $name => $number){
    echo ", ".$name." " .$number;
  }
}
//output will be:

0, walson 986, john 01, merry 234
1, nelson 987, richard 01, joan 345
2, danny 989, soffie 02, roland 345
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24710510)

Comment: TocToc i think so question is: "How can I get output like this in PHP".
so can u explain me why isnt answer for question?

Comment: the question seems ambiguous (this is is also why you probably use "should", because you are not sure what is asked). It is ok to make assumption when the question is not sufficiently precise, but in that case you can ask for details or explicit the assumption of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Below picture is showing output. It will solve your problem.

```
[![<?php 
$array  = array();
$next\['items'\] = array(

  array(

    'walson' => '986' ,
            'john' => '01' ,
            'merry' => '234' 

  ),
    array(

    'nelson' => '987' ,
            'richard' => '01' ,
            'joan' => '345' 

  ),
  array(

    'danny' => '989' ,
            'soffie' => '02' ,
            'roland' => '345' 

  )

);


$array\[\] = $next;
//print_r($array);

foreach($array\[0\]\['items'\] as $key => $value ){
  $str = '';
  $c=0;
   foreach($value as $key_ =>$value_){
     if($c==0){
   $str .=$key;
       $c=1;
     }
   $str .=' '. $key_." ".$value_;
   }
  echo $str."<br>";

}

?>][1]][1]
```